# How to get UICollectionViewCell in GetSizeForItem in Xamarin.Forms (iOS)?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In a subclass of `UICollectionViewSource` how can I get the cell at a given `indexPath` if the cell is not accessible from the collectionView?

```
class CVS : UICollectionViewSource
{
    string[] data = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

    public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        return data.Length;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var textCell = (CVC)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(CVC.CellId, indexPath);
        textCell.Text = data[indexPath.Row];
        return textCell;
    }

    public override void ItemSelected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Row {0} selected", indexPath.Row);
    }

    public override bool ShouldSelectItem(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return true;
    }

    [Export("collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:"), CompilerGenerated]
    public virtual CGSize GetSizeForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cells = collectionView.Subviews.Where(sv => sv is CVC).Cast<CVC>().ToList();
        var cell = collectionView.CellForItem(indexPath);
        Debug.WriteLine($"{cells.Count} {cell?.SizeThatFits(new CGSize()) ?? new CGSize()}");
        return new CGSize(100, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: well, GetSizeForItem is defined in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` not  `UICollectionViewSource ` . and it is used to describe the item size, why do you want to get the cell?

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT the same thing happened to me with `UITableView`, what I did then was to drop altogether using `GetHeightForRow` and the table is using the height of the cell I instantiated in `GetCell`. I'll try the same approach with `UICollectionView` when I get the chance.

Comment: what is your  exact problem ? Does `GetSizeForItem` not get called ? or `collectionView.CellForItem(indexPath);` not work?

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT I'd like to have access to the cell at the given `indexPath` to be able to compute its size, but there isn't a way to do that from `GetHeightForRow` nor `GetSizeForItem`. Besides, it seems the collection and table both get the size from the cell returned in `GetCell` if `GetHeightForRow` and `GetSizeForItem` are not overridden. So, at this point, I'm dropping overriding `GetHeightForRow` and `GetSizeForItem`.